# Elasticsearch wildcard works fine but query_string does not

Tags: elasticsearch

A have names stored in Elasticsearch and I want to use wildcard to search them. So when I use query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should":
                {
                    "wildcard" : { "name1" : "абаев а*" }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

it works fine. But now Im trying to implement multiple fields search:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should":
                {
                    "query_string" : { 
                        "query" : "абаев*",
                        "fields": ["name1", "name2"],
                        "default_operator": "AND"
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

and this query doesn't work.

Analyzer for fields:

```
{
    'analyzer': {
        'keyword_lowercase': {
            'tokenizer': 'keyword',
            'filter': 'lowercase'
        }
    }
}
```

Docs examples:

```
{
    "name1": "Абаева Хрестиния",
    "name2": "Абаева Арестиния"
}

{
    "name1": "Аиб Мария"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In your query string query, try to add `analyze_wildcard: true` (false by default) as well since you have a wildcard at the end

Comment: I did it so result is still bad.

Comment: You should provide some example documents you have, and what result you expect, otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can it be: the reason is coz of I`m tokenizing values to keywords, so ESS cannot find "Абаева AND Х*" in ['Абаева', 'Хрестиния']?